# parameterising the bigquerry dataset name for substitution variables in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, parameters

I am using "**insert into** "command for certain table in GCP but for different environments(live either dev , or prod ). I want to  just replace certain part of dataset like "**dataset1_dv.tablename**" into "**dataset1_pd.tablename**" . by using *ENV substitution variables .something Like this (dataset1*{ENV}.tablename).

How do I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have dynamic dataset (the true reason is BigQuery need to know the region where to run the query. If the dataset is not set at query start (even variable evaluation) BigQuery don't know the region and can't create a job).

To achieve this, you need to create a [dynamic query with execute immediate](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#execute_immediate). In summary

- create your query as a string with string function of BigQuery and replace the dataset by your variable
- use Execute Immediate to execute your string (your dynamic query)

You can wrap those operation in a procedure if you want to simplify the use.